# What does the compiler do in assembly when optimizing code? ie -O2 flag

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

So when you add an optimization flag when compiling your C++, it runs faster, but how does this work? Could someone explain what really goes on in the assembly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means you're making the compiler do extra work / analysis at compile time, so you can reap the rewards of a few extra precious cpu cycles at runtime. Might be best to explain with an example.

Consider a loop like this:

```
const int n = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  cout << "bleh" << endl;
```

If you compile this without optimizations, the compiler will not do any extra work for you -- assembly generated for this code snippet will likely be a literal translation into compare and jump instructions. (which isn't the fastest, just the most straightforward)

However, if you compile WITH optimizations, the compiler can easily `inline` this loop since it knows the upper bound can't ever change because `n` is `const`. (i.e. it can copy the repeated code 5 times directly instead of comparing / checking for the terminating loop condition).

Here's another example with an optimized function call. Below is my whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int foo(int a, int b) {
  return a * b;
} 


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", foo(10, 15));
  return 0;
}
```

If i compile this code without optimizations using `gcc foo.c` on my x86 machine, my assembly looks like this:

```
movq    %rsi, %rax
movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
movl    $10, %eax      ; these are my parameters to
movl    $15, %ecx      ; the foo function
movl    %eax, %edi
movl    %ecx, %esi
callq   _foo
; .. about 20 other instructions ..
callq   _fprintf
```

Here, it's not optimizing anything. It's loading the registers with my constant values and calling my `foo` function. But look if i recompile with the `-O2` flag:

```
movq    (%rax), %rdi
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rsi
movl    $150, %edx
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _fprintf
```

The compiler is so smart that it doesn't even call `foo` anymore. It just inlines it's return value.

Comment: Very cool! Is there a difference when you're doing things like calling functions too?

Comment: @TidusSmith updated answer with more in depth example. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the optimization happens in the compiler's intermediate representation before the assembly is generated. You should definitely check out Agner Fog's [Software optimization resources](http://www.agner.org/optimize/). Chapter 8 of the 1st manual describes optimizations performed by the compiler with examples.