# Are modern C++ compilers able to avoid calling a const function twice under some conditions?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, call

For instance, if I have this code:

```
class SomeDataProcessor
{
public:
    bool calc(const SomeData & d1, const SomeData & d2) const;
private:
    //Some non-mutable, non-static member variables
}

SomeDataProcessor sdp;
SomeData data1;
SomeData data2;

someObscureFunction(sdp.calc(data1, data2),
                    sdp.calc(data1, data2));
```

Let's consider the **potentially** equivalent code:

```
bool b = sdp.calc(data1, data2);
someObscureFunction(b,b);
```

For this to be valid, the `calc()` function should meet some requirements, and for the example I call the property `_pure_const_formula_`

A `_pure_const_formula_` would:

- Not change any member, static or global variable state
- Call only `_pure_const_formula_` functions
- Maybe some other conditions that I don't have in mind

For instance, calling a random number generator would not fit these requirements.

Is the compiler allowed to replace the first code with the second one, even if it needs to dig recursively into called functions? Are modern compilers able to do this?

Comment: you can find more info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had left some code from a more complex code example...

Comment: Are we assuming that the definition of `calc` is visible to the compiler, as it would be if whole-program optimization (aka link-time code generation) is available? That makes a big difference here; it changes the answer entirely.

Comment: If the compiler can see the implementation though inline declaration or LTO then yes it can remove duplicate calls. Otherwise you need to use compiler specific tricks to do it.

Comment: @ZanLynx and CodyGray: +1billion. LTO (or inline definition) makes questions like this a no-brainer: the answer is then an absolute _yes_: any optimisation is possible, as the function's body can be a candidate for inlining at any call site, with all the possible optimisations that enables.

Comment: I guess adding `constexpr` can further improve optimization in some cases

Comment: @Xeverous Which cases? Adding it to where? Surely marking a function as `constexpr` means its definition must be visible in the same translation unit, in which case, it would already be known that it would return the same results both times, and that optimisation would be applied.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

GCC has the `pure` [attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (used as `__attribute__((pure))`) for functions which tells the compiler that redundant calls can be eliminated. It's used e.g. on `strlen`.

I'm not aware of any compiler doing this automatically, especially considering the fact that the functions to be called may not be available in source form, and the object file formats contain no metadata about whether a function is pure or not.

Comment: Aha, thanks for this very useful answer. I had exactly that kind of idea in mind, ie a somewhat expensive .depth() tree iterator member function.

Comment: Keep in mind that even with the `pure` attribute, gcc would only elide redundant calls if it can determine through static analysis that they're indeed called with the same parameters. If the compiler cannot do this, you can still eliminate redundant calls through memoization, but a C/C++ compiler won't do that automatically for you.

Comment: Pure function determination is an extremely common compiler optimization, in most languages.  It's difficult in C (mostly due to pointers) but even GCC will attempt to do it with the compiler flag `-Wsuggest-attribute=pure` (which emits a warning when it thinks a function can be marked `pure`)

Comment: How is `strlen` pure? If you call it twice with the same argument you [may get 2 different results](https://ideone.com/fv5gsA).

Comment: @nwp you're modifying the string so it's not the same argument. The pointer is the same, but the data it points to had been modified.

Comment: According to the documentation modifying the string is allowed. The condition you linked to is *"declare that a function [...] returns a value depending only on its arguments (pure)*", so besides that anything goes. Is that a bug in the documentation or am I just reading it wrong?

Comment: @nwp: I think it's intended to be interpreted as 'depending only on its arguments or any memory (transitively) accessible through its arguments'. Otherwise it wouldn't even be able to calculate the string length at all.

Comment: @nwp : Joren is right, the documentation refers to any data that is accessible from the passed arguments. For example passing a pointer to a global variable won't ever be elided, because the compiler cannot make sure that the global is not modified by some other thread.

Comment: Regarding threading and globals -- compilers are indeed allowed to assume that other threads don't modify globals, absent insertion of memory barriers and whatnot.

Answer (score 23):

**Yes, absolutely.**

[Compilers do this all the time, and more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20111516/560648).

For example, if all your function did were return `true`, and its definition were visible to the compiler at the callsite, the entire function call would probably be elided, resulting in just:

```
someObscureFunction(true, true);
```

A program for which the compiler has sufficient information may be "optimised" from a quite complex chain of tasks down to perhaps one or two instructions. Now, actually operating on member variables is pushing the optimiser to its limit to some degree, but if the variables are `private`, are given a known initial value, and are not mutated by any other member function, I don't see why a compiler couldn't just inline its known value if it wanted to. Compilers are very, very smart.

People think that a compiled program is a one-to-one mapping of lines in your source code, but this is almost never true. The entire purpose of C++ is that it is an *abstraction* of what your computer's actually going to be doing when it runs your program.

Comment: You are assuming that the function is defined inline. However, the function declared and used in the OP is most certainly not defined inline. And the optimizer is powerless in estimating purity of functions for which it cannot see any source code. So "Yes, absolutely" is absolutely false, both in general, and especially in the context of the question.

Comment: @cmaster: Read the answer again. _"if all your function did were return true, **and its definition were visible to the compiler at the callsite**, the entire function call would probably be elided"_ I'm not "assuming" anything!

Comment: @cmaster: _"However, the function declared and used in the OP is most certainly not defined inline."_ It doesn't compile, either.

Comment: @cmaster In addition to Lightness’ other observations, link-time optimisation can cause the function be inlined even across object boundaries.

Comment: I've seen clang do a number of optimizations that people never thought compilers would be able to do (sometimes with horrible results due to people relying on that belief) with link-time optimization.

Comment: @cmaster MSVC, Clang and GCC have all supported LTO for some years now, so notions like "defined inline" are rapidly becoming dated from an optimization point of view.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Arguably LTO means that at the "compiler" gets to examine the definition at link time at the callsite.

Comment: @Leushenko: Plus, "defined inline" was always irrelevant if the definition was visible in the same TU.

Comment: Well, there are a lot of people who still link without link time optimizations, as link time optimizations tend to be irrelevant with well written code (= no insane repeated calls across compilation unit boundaries within the inner loop of the application). If you want to base your answer on link time optimizations being switched on, that's fine, but then you should say so explicitly.

Comment: @cmaster: I didn't base my answer on that, as I've explained a few times now

Comment: This isn't kindergarten; the constraints are clearly labelled. I see no reason to turn the answer into lego! The question literally asks for these conditions, and I have provided them. All one must do is _read_.

Answer (score 10):

No, given the shown code, the compiler cannot guarantee that the proposed optimization will have no observable differences, and no modern compiler will be able to optimize away the second function call.

A very simple example: this class method might use a random number generator, and save the result in some private buffer, that some other part of the code reads later on. Obviously, eliminating a function call now results in fewer randomly-generated values being placed in that buffer.

In other words, just because a class method is `const` does not mean that it has no observable side effects when it's called.

Comment: Rand() would change a global and OP asked if compilers were smart enough to check for changing globals.

Comment: Yes, I had in mind the RNG case, but this one requires at least a static or global variable, so if the compiler can examine the functions called inside calc() to check if they change a global state, would the compiler be able to do that kind of optimization?

Comment: OP already said there would be constraints. You just repeated them. If you want to take the code in the question as gospel, literally, verbatim, then you have to throw away half the question prose and report that the program won't even compile, let alone link, let alone be optimised.

Comment: `no modern compiler` Are you deliberately using a restrictive definition of _compiler_ to not include link-time optimisation? Because **all** of the major modern compiler toolchains trivially support LTO, which means the definition of the function can be considered for optimisation at every call site. (Of course, even those that don't could optimise this if the function is declared in the header and they can see its lack of other side effects.)

Comment: There are modern compilers (clang, for example) that can often tell that the proposed optimization has no observable differences and do in fact optimize away the second function call. Of course any compiler that makes this optimization where it's illegal is broken, but there's no reason a compiler can't make the optimization where it is legal. (And there are dozens of examples of people assuming compilers would never be smart enough to make particular optimizations and then getting badly burned when they were.)

Answer (score 4):

No, the compiler is not allowed to do that in this case. The `const` only means you do not change the state of the object the method belongs to. However, invoking this method multiple times with the same input parameters might give different results. For example, think of a method that produces a random result.

Comment: I had in mind the RNG case, but this one requires at least a static or global variable, so if the compiler can examine the functions called inside calc() to check if they are

Comment: _"invoking this method multiple times with the same input parameters might give different results"_ Right, but the compiler can often see when that's not the case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, but then again in most of these cases, the compiler doesn't even need the const keyword.

Comment: Of course, a `mutable` field would screw things up further too

Comment: @Axel: Yes, indeed.

Comment: @MarkKCowan: And let's not forget `volatile`!

Comment: On a trolling note, if the compiler memoises `random()` which `returns a randomly generated number`, giving it the same (yet still technically "randomly-generated") result for every invocation during execution, but a different value for each execution, is the program still satisfying its specification?  XKCD did something along these lines a while back...

Comment: @MarkKCowan xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, modern C compilers can elide redundant function calls *if and only if* they can prove that such an optimization behaves *as-if* the original program semantics were followed. For example, that means means they could eliminate multiple calls to the same function with the same arguments, if the function has no side-effects and if its return value depends only on the arguments.

Now, you asked specifically about `const` - this is mostly useful to the developer, and not the coder. A `const` function is a *hints* that the method doesn't modify the object it is called on, and `const` arguments are *hints* that the arguments are not modified. However, the function may (legally<sup>1</sup>) cast away the `const`-ness of the `this` pointer or of its arguments. So the compiler can't rely on it.

Furthermore, even if `const` objects passed to a function really were never modified within that function, and `const` functions never modified the receiver object, the method could easily rely on mutable global data (and could mutate such data). Consider, for example, a function that returns the current time, or which increments a global counter.

So the `const` declarations help the programmer, not the compiler<sup>2</sup>.

However, the compiler might be able to use other tricks to prove the calls are redundant:

- The function may be in the same compilation unit as the caller, allowing the compiler to inspect it and determine exactly what it relies on. The ultimate form of this is inlining: the function body may be moved into the caller at which point the optimizer can remove redundant code from later calls (up to an including all the code from those calls entirely and perhaps all or port of the original call too).
- The toolchain may use some type of link-time-optimization, which effectively allows the type of analysis described in the point above even for functions and callers in different compilation units. This could allow this optimization for *any* code present when the final executable is being generated.
- The compiler may allow the user to annotate a function with an attribute that informs the compiler that it may treat the function as not having side-effects. For example, gcc provides the [`pure`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bpure_007d-function-attribute-3343) and `const` function attributes which inform `gcc` that the functions has no side effects, and depend only on their parameters (and on global variables, in the case of `pure`).

---

1 <sub>Usually, as long as the object wasn't originally defined as `const`.</sub>

2 <sub>There is at one sense in which `const` *definitions* do help the compiler: they can put global objects defined as `const` into a read-only section of the executable (if such a feature exists) and also combine such objects when they are equal (e.g., identical string constants).</sub>