# What is the running time of T(n)= T(n/2) + T(n/2) + n^2?

Tags: algorithm, performance, recursion

I know it seems to you somehow easy but there is something that preoccupied my mind these days. Do these two equations have the same running time?

1) T(n)=  T(n/2) + T(n/2) + n^2 ?

2) T(n)=  2T(n/2) + n^2 ?

because in 1 the compiler must calls each time for each T, but in 2 there is only on call the return result will be multiple by 2. in 1 we have a tree, I mean each time we need to call two times for T,

I think I found my mistake I am not sure,
F(n) = F(n/2) + .... is different from T(n)!!

if we write a code { return f(n) + f(n)}
it must be different from return 2*f(n) based on running time. without optimization of compilers

Comment: It depends on whether `T` in your "equation" is representing running time, or something else.

Comment: If the compiler can see the code for `T()` and `T()` has no side-effects, that optimisation is possible. This is true for C-like languages, at least, as far as I understand, but I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are modern C++ compilers able to avoid calling a const function twice under some conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227535/are-modern-c-compilers-able-to-avoid-calling-a-const-function-twice-under-some)

Comment: @BenVoigt it is running time.

Comment: @KenY-N I did not talked about a special compiler, So I think my Q was not deserved a minus!!!!!

Comment: Can you tell me what is the condition for the recursion to stop?

Comment: The line that starts with *"I think I found my mistake ..."* is very true. The `T(n)` equations normally represent mathematical sequences used to determine the time complexity of algorithms. They aren't function calls.

Comment: *if we write a code { return f(n) + f(n)} it must be different from return 2*f(n) based on running time. without optimization of compilers*. It depends on a million other things like the language/system you are using. If the language is not even compiled, then there will be no compiler optimizations, either!

Answer (score 1):

Both algorithms are in the O(log n) class, but option #2 will always be faster in practice.

Function calling is universally slower than integer multiplication, and generally it is *significantly* slower; this will be true even in those situations where the determinism of T can be exploited to efficiently cache the results of each T(x).

**EDIT:** It appears that I have misunderstood the OP.

I understood the OP to be asking about two different but mathematically equivalent implementations of a particular recursive function T(n), which returned the sum of n^2 + 2(n/2)^2 + 4(n/4)^2 + ... + n(n/n)^2, assuming T(1) = 1 and n is a perfect power of 2.

Implementation #1 called T() twice for each level of recursion. I incorrectly stated that such an algorithm would be O(log n), when in fact it is O(2n - 1), or more simply O(n).

Implementation #2 called T() only once for each level of recursion, which makes it O(log n). It is therefore likely to be the faster of the two.

I now understand that T() was meant to be the Time function for some other algorithm! My mistake. Obviously, in that case, a solution for O() would be dominated by the n^2 term.

Comment: Wait what. How can the function be O(log n) if there is a n^2 in there? And when talking recurrences and asymptotic analysis, how is function calling as in jumping to another instruction in memory related to that at all? T(n/2) + T(n/2) = 2T(n/2), the two recurrences are exactly the same. I know what OP is referring two, but recurrences are just the wrong tool to represent this.

Comment: LOG (n)!!!!!!. are you joking. I know the running time but I just wanted to be sure about the differences