# How is done compile-time calculation/math operation in gcc?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64

If I compile a program with `-O2` optimization, then a any function with math operations is done "inline", without physicall cpu instruction in assembly [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111440/what-does-the-compiler-do-in-assembly-when-optimizing-code-ie-o2-flag). So having this in `c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f(int a, int b, int c){
    return a*b+c;
}
int main(){
    printf("%i\n",f(1,2,4));
    return 0;
}
```

And compiled as `cc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S a.c`, gas output:

```
.text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  f
    .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB22:
# a.c:5:    return a*b+c;
    imull   %esi, %edi  # b, tmp93
# a.c:5:    return a*b+c;
    leal    (%rdi,%rdx), %eax   #, tmp92
# a.c:6: }
    ret 
.LFE22:
    .size   f, .-f
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "%i\n"
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB23:
    subq    $8, %rsp    #,
# a.c:8:    printf("%i\n",f(1,2,4));
    movl    $6, %esi    # HERE, I can change the value and gcc will not even notice
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi    #,
    xorl    %eax, %eax  #
    call    printf@PLT  #
# a.c:10: }
    xorl    %eax, %eax  #
    addq    $8, %rsp    # 
    ret 
.LFE23:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Here can you see, the the `f` function will not even be called from main. So the function is simply avoided and its return value is calculated somehow in compile time to some instruction cycles. But how is math calculation done in *compile-time*, when compiler does not directly operate upon CPU, which only does assembly? Or does compiler in compil-time perform some cpu task before compiled to asm? Why is then asm needed, when compiler can directly translate to opcode and execute program without "by-step" of assembler?

Comment: Where else would the compiler operate than on your CPU? Why can’t it do math if Calculator.exe or Excel can?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen if you would compile without any optimization, there would be a asm generated source for that calculation. And asm is one-by-one mapping to opcode generation for CPU. Compiler is not. And so if compiler is bypassing the asm generation by "inline-ing" it, there must some inter-compiler instruction doing that job instead of asm. So I would like to know that inter-compiler source for that. And it is also interesting, that only on `-O2` is it perform, on less or no optimization, in it normaly generated to asm (as alread said), so this inter-compiler instructions are not always perfom

Comment: Assembly is not one-to-one mapping to opcodes always. There doesn’t need to be any “inter-compiler” things. The compiler optimizes things if you ask it to. The compiler already transforms the code you write into binary, why is it so strange to think it can transform constants also? It knows 2*4 is 8 so it can just say 8. And yes, optimizations are only done when optimizations are asked for. It would be bad for the compiler to do things the used didn’t ask it to.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen `It knows 2*4 is 8`, thats the thing, how does compiler knows it without asm? As far as I know, the compilation steps involve asm-generation *before* binary/object transformation, so not sure with statement `he compiler already transforms the code you write into binary`. Also, if there is a special treatment with constants called `constant folding` you are talking about, then why is it feature of only optimizated code? Why is it regarded as optimization at all? The `constant folding` could be perform on all basic program, if it is feature of gcc.

Comment: Or does gcc developers classify, what feature will be strictly for optimization and what will be as "basic/new" feature of gcc?

Comment: How would assembly know that 2*4 is 8? How does Excel know it’s that? It doesn’t do any assembly anywhere. It calculates it, just like the compiler. There’s no need to produce assembly before outputting opcodes. Assembly is just the human readable form, compilers don’t need it. And what I mean is the compiler already takes all the code you write and knows how to output opcodes for multiple processors based on it, but it’s strange that it can calculate things? The reason why optimization isn’t done unless asked is due to debugging, for example.

Comment: A compiler takes the code you write, understands it, and outputs something that does what you wanted based on the code. That is a very complex thing to do. It doesn’t simply do “oh here’s a loop I’ll write a loop in assembly.” It can do a lot more, as long as the result is what it should be based on your code.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, c source -> preprocessed source -> assembly source -> object code -> linker -> executable. If I did not go through assembly, then how would I generate object needed for linker? But with `-O2`, I evidently can, as you claim. How?

Comment: Gcc does indeed generate assembly code, but others do not.  For example, clang directly generates machine code, only outputting assembly code if you explicitly request it.  But that's besides the point: optimisations like constant folding and inlining happen on an *intermediate representation* long before any assembly or machine code is generated.  This intermediate representation is internal to the compiler and usually not exposed to the user.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is a program and it simply carries out the calculation required.  It does not simulate a CPU to do so and this step (known as *constant folding*) happens long before any instructions are generated.

Comment: Then why can I see *without* optimization a physical asm instruction to perform the calculation, and with optimization, there is it done "inline" without even callling the `f` function, so in the end, the `f` function is redundant. What is done in your mentioned `constant folding`? And why is it called on `-O2` and not in `-O1` (no optimization)?

Comment: @autistic456 Constant folding is a compiler optimisation where the compiler evaluates expressions involving only constants instead of generating code for them.  In your code, this is only possible after `f` has been *inlined,* so you only observe the effect when inlining is enabled.  This happens at `-O2` or better but not `-O1`.

Comment: Note that `-O1` is not “no optimisation” (that would be `-O0`).  Rather, it's “optimisation level 1” i.e. “little optimisation.”  Refer to the manual for the different optimisation levels and their effects.

Comment: then there is another concept - `inlining`. How is it done in gcc, and why is it perform only on `-O2` or higher? And - `compiler evaluates expressions` - still, how is it done, wihout cpu-opcode for arithmetic operation? It only means, compiler does some "inter-instructions" call on cpu, without generating a asm. So gcc inter-calling bypass asm and does some their own work. How is that possible?

Comment: it would be enought to explain your mentioned `inline-ing` of the compiler to your answer, because that could explain, what is compiler doing in that optimization

Comment: *Inlining* is an optimisation where a function is copy-pasted into the place where it is called instead of calling the function.  This optimisation happens long before the compiler generates any machine code and does not involve any special opcodes.  How exactly it is done is rather involved and too much to explain in the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.  I recommend you to read an introductory text on compiler design instead.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what an “inter-instruction call” is supposed to be.  I believe you have a wrong mental model about how a compiler works.

Comment: it is, of course a good idea to read a book for the compiler design and I was thinking about it, to read https://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811 dragon book - compilers techniques. Unfortunatelly, it has over 1000 pages, And is very theoretical. I would need some resource with examples and c implementation of the compiler to understand, for example of this `inline-ing` in real. So if you know a good references with real examples of compiler design, I would be glad.

Comment: @autistic456 Unfortunately, compilers capable of such optimisations are quite complicated programs.  I don't know any that is simple enough to be understandable while also being sophisticated enough to illustrate the principle of inlining.

Comment: it would be enough a reference to a simple one. But only real-examples are required. I do not know if such reference exitsts, but if you know about one, please let know